# Can I use Java SE libraries in Java SE embedded on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: java

I wonder if I can use Java SE libraries (like the ones we use when designing desktop apps via Java) in Java SE embedded which can be installed on a Raspberry Pi.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

An example is shown on [Getting Started with Java® SE Embedded on the Raspberry Pi](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html), by Bill Courington and Gary Collins.

> **How to get Linux and Java SE Embedded running on the Raspberry Pi in
>   less than an hour**
>
> It is hardly larger than a credit card. It costs about the same as a
>   book on Java programming.
>
> It's the Raspberry Pi computer, and it can support a full Java SE
>   runtime for headless embedded applications. This article gets you
>   started with Java on the Raspberry Pi programming with these topics:
>
> - [The Raspberry Pi](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html#Raspberry): A brief introduction
> - [Prerequisites](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html#Prerequisites): What you need to have and know
> - [Essential Linux Setup](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html#Essential): How to install Debian Linux
> - [Java SE Embedded Setup](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html#Java): How to acquire and install Java SE Embedded
> - [Optional Linux Tuning and Tweaking](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html#Optional): How to make Linux work better for you
>
> NOTE: There are many potential variations of the instructions given
>   here, especially which operations you execute on a host (desktop or
>   laptop) computer, and which you execute on the Raspberry Pi. Use your
>   knowledge and preferences (and perhaps some of the topics in the
>   [Optional Linux Tuning and Tweaking section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html#Optional)) to create a workflow
>   that works for you.

Here is the Java SE Embedded Setup:

> - In the host computer’s web browser go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javase/index.html.
>     The web page might have changed in detail since this article was
>     written.
> - In the Java SE Embedded 7 column, click EABI, VFP, SoftFB ABI, Little Endian.  A survey page appears.
> - Complete the survey and click Submit. A verification page appears.
> - Examine the verification page for correctness (in particular, your email address), then click Submit.  In a short time, an email from
>     JavaSE-Embedded-LinkNotify appears in your inbox.
> - Click the link in the email. Another download page appears (some details might have changed since this article was written):
> - Select Accept License Agreement, then click the link in the ARMv6/7 Linux - Headless row.
>
> NOTE: At the time this article was written, the ARMv7 Linux - Headful
>   software had not been tested on the Raspberry Pi. The ARMv7 Linux -
>   Headless - Server Compiler software does not work on the Raspberry Pi
>   because that software requires an ARM v7 chip.
>
> - Save the `.gz` file to your `Downloads` directory.
> - Login over the network to the Raspberry Pi as user pi, and create a directory for the Java download:
>
>   `$ ssh pi@RaspberryIP mkdir /home/pi/java`
> - Copy the Java download to the new directory on the Raspberry Pi:
>
>   `$ scp ~/Downloads/*.gz pi@RaspberryIP:/home/pi/java`
> - Unpack the Java download:
>
>   `$ ssh pi@RaspberryIP`
>
>   `$ cd /home/pi/java`
>
>   `$ tar -zxvf *.gz`
>
>   `...`
> - Launch Java:
>
>   `$ ls ejre*`
>
>   `ejre1.7.0_04`
>
>   `$ cd ejre*`
>
>   `$ ./bin/java -version`
>
>   `java version "1.7.0_04-ea"`
>
>   `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment for Embedded (build 1.7.0_04-ea-b20, headless)`
>
>   `Java Hotspot(TM) Embedded Client VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)`
>
>   Some details, such as version and build numbers, might have changed
>     since this article was written.
> - Optionally, remove the download file:
>
>   `$ rm /home/pi/java/*.gz`